# Could not convert class android.os.UserHandle

Tags: android, react-native

After some time I came back to one of our project and suddenly find out that after installing debug build on Android the app is working as expected. But, after killing it and attempting to open again it fails with Could not convert class android.os.UserHandle error. I don’t use UserHandle nowhere in my code, so I can't check import statement or arguments that is passed to this class.

React Native Version
0.67.5

I'm not sure is it related because I don't use react-native-notifications, but I use getLaunchOptions() in MainActivity with new ReactActivityDelegate to pass notification from android layer to JS, so I tried this solution wix/react-native-notifications#287 (comment) but it's not working for me.

I'm facing this problem only on Xiaomi Redmi Note 11S. It may exist on other devices, but additionally I was able to check only Samsung and it's ok there.

Is anybody faced the same?

There is a screenshot of fail.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nI7G.jpg)